# How to get this kind of maintaining data, such as used storage, in CRM 2011 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I want to make an application to retrieve some data, such as used storage, the amount of current users, in CRM 2011 Online.
This idea was generated by Resource in Use section, which was in `Setting -> Administration -> Resources In Use`.

I thought this data wasn't held in CRM, I doubt it was held in Office365. Are there some people can tell me how to do it?

Comment: So the information you want to retrieve is the number of users, and how much storage they've used?

Comment: yes, do you know how to do it? Thanks!